# Changing(replacing) a value in a list without using range(len())

Tags: python, algorithm, sorting

My purpose is to change the value of the elements 3 and 4 to 4 and 3 and I have written a function that takes a list, first number and second number as arguments:

```
def pre9(the_list, value_to_replace, the_replacing_value):

    for i in the_list:
        if i == value_to_replace:
            value_to_replace = the_replacing_value
        elif i == the_replacing_value:
            the_replacing_value = value_to_replace

    return the_list
```

I then assign a test-case to a variabel and then print it:

test_pre9 = pre9([1,2,3,4,5,7,3,4], 3, 4)
print(test_pre9)

The result is: [1,2,3,4,5,7,3,4]
I expect it to be: [1,2,4,3,5,7,4,3]

I have for a long time ago written a code that accoplishes this task:

```
def uppgift_9():
    the_list = [3,5,8,9,4,5]

    for i in range(len(the_list)-1):
        temp = the_list[3]
        the_list[3] = the_list[4]
        the_list[4] = temp
    return the_list
```

But I've read in many places that using range(len()) is not "pythonic" and it is possible to do anything without using it.

Does anyone know why my code fails?

Comment: Why do you need to iterate the array if you just want to swap elements at 3, 4? Just swap elements at 3, 4 and done Or you want to change element with value 3 to that of with value 4 and vice versa? Please make your question clear.

Comment: Thank you but Djerro Neth have understood the question and suggested a viable change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't actually change the item in the list, try this:

```
def pre9(the_list, value_to_replace, the_replacing_value):
    for i, value in enumerate(the_list):
        if value == value_to_replace:
            the_list[i] = the_replacing_value
        elif value == the_replacing_value:
            the_list[i] = value_to_replace
    return the_list
```

Now the list will have the actually items changed to what you wanted it to be. Enumerate() returns the index and value of an item in a list, it's very handy! And indeed, the range(len()) is not very pythonic and is usually used when people jump from other languages like Java, C# etc. Using enumerate() is the correct 'pythonic' way of achieving this.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, it is exactly what I wanted. I had thought of enumerate but only now after your comment do I have a more clear understanding of the concept. 

i keeps track of the index and value keeps its value. If I want to check a value, I use value == xxx and if I want to change a value, I use the_list[i] = xxx.